# Misunderstanding of C# SerialPort.Write() method

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

My task is to send input data to a serial port throught a code. I use .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. I have an example that successfully handle data from the scanner and I want to simulate this programmatically. It seems that C# SerialPort.Write() fits for that, but port_DataReceived handler doesn't do anything:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication_ReadTabel
{
    class SerialPortProgram
    {
        private SerialPort port; 

        string input = "";

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new SerialPortProgram();
        }

        private SerialPortProgram()
        {
            port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data:");

            port.DataReceived += new
            SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

            port.Open();

            port.Write("ghghgh");

            Console.Read();
        }

        private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            input = port.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            Console.WriteLine("----");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of .net are you using? Core or Framework?

Comment: Please search for the word loopback test to understand its contents. Unless the transmission and reception of the same port are connected by hardware, the contents written to the port cannot be read from the same port.

Comment: I use .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kunif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014308/kunif) is right. We can't write and read simultaneously at the same port via code (at least by using .NET Framework 4). So decision is to use free software [com0com](https://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/) for creating a connection between 2 virtual ports. The first one calls write() method, the second one handles an input signal.

```
class SerialPortProgram
{
    private SerialPort port, port2;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new SerialPortProgram();
    }

    private SerialPortProgram()
    {
        port = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.Open();

        port2 = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);           
        port2.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port2_DataReceived);
        port2.Open();

        port.Write("Hello!");

        Console.Read();
    }

    void port2_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("COM4 incoming data:");
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        string inp = port2.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine(inp);
        Console.WriteLine("----");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is Console.Read();
you can try this

```
namespace ConsoleApplication_ReadTabel
{
    class SerialPortProgram
    {
        private SerialPort port; 

        string input = "";

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new SerialPortProgram();
        }

        private SerialPortProgram()
        {
            port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

            Console.WriteLine("Incoming Data:");

            port.DataReceived += new
            SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

            port.Open();

            port.Write("ghghgh");

            Console.Read();//when program is waiting here, send something the port and continue

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Console.Read();
        }

        private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            input = port.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            Console.WriteLine("----");
        }
    }
}
```